# Slimbox set max width for "pop-up" image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm using [slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox/) to create a pop-up image option.

Everything works as expected but I want to add a "restriction" to the max size of an image after it's been poped-up.

I now have an image with a width of `3572px`. I have no control over the image size my clients upload to the website so I need to set a max width for them.

I have looked at the css that create the box but I can't find a way to add a `max-width` element to any class or id.

Here is the output of the page if an image is clicked:

```
<div id="lbOverlay" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 0.8;"></div>
<div id="lbCenter" class="" style="top: 0px; width: 3572px; height: 2164px; margin-left: -1786px; left: 840px;">
    <div id="lbImage" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1; background-image: url("http://www.xxx.nl/large-image.jpg");"></div>
    <div style="position: relative; width: 3552px; height: 2144px;"></div>
</div>
```

But I think that somewhere in the `.js` the size of the image is calculated.
My `.js` sucks so I won't be able to find it (I still gonna try)

I hope anyone uses slimbox and can help me!

M.

---------- UPDATE -----------
Crap; I found this:
[SlimBox FAQ](https://github.com/cbeyls/slimbox/wiki/FAQ#can-slimbox-automatically-resize-my-images-when-they-are-too-large-to-be-contained-in-the-browser-window)